# Jquery returns a list using id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble with jquery and selectors using the following code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
console.log($('#test'));
```

This always returns a list like `[<div id=​"test">​</div>​]` instead of the single element.

This results on always having to write `$('#test')[0]` for every operations instead of only `$('#test')`. Any idea on why?

Regards

Comment: what u want to retrieve? data between `<div id="test">` ?

Comment: as you ask why this is happening (not how to avoid it) and it was answered, it can just comment this: you may try `document.getElementById('test')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jquery will not return the HtmlElement, it returns a jQuery object.

> A jQuery object contains a collection
>   of Document Object Model (DOM)
>   elements that have been created from
>   an HTML string or selected from a
>   document. Since jQuery methods often
>   use CSS selectors to match elements
>   from a document, the set of elements
>   in a jQuery object is often called a
>   set of "matched elements" or "selected
>   elements"
>
> The jQuery object itself behaves much
>   like an array; it has a length
>   property and the elements in the
>   object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1].
>   Note that a jQuery object is not
>   actually a Javascript Array object, so
>   it does not have all the methods of a
>   true Array object such as join().
>   http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

This is an example of the **Composite Design Pattern**

The Composite Pattern describes a group of objects that can be treated in the same way a single instance of an object can. Implementing this pattern allows you to treat both individual objects and compositions in a uniform manner. In jQuery, when we're accessing or performing actions on a single DOM element or a group of DOM elements, we can treat both in a uniform manner. http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjquery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery encapsulates any objects found for a number of reasons.  For one, it ensures that no matter what, null will never be returned for example.  Rather, the elements found are inserted into a list.  The fact that even though you're searching for a single element, the mechanism always remains the same and therefore the results will be placed into an array of one element rather than the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it is better to think of selectors as matching multiple items, and your solution would be best if you use the each syntax to iterate through the matches items...

```
$('#test').each(function() { 
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score -3):

As ID is not unique, jQuery looks for every element with such ID. So it's always returns a list, because threre is no guarantee that the element is exactly one

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  Every DOM element's ID *must* be unique, or the document is invalid.  The following is from jQuery's documentation (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

"Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid."